# Regular expression for replacing numbers doesn't work with 'sed'

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Using Linux bash.

I have the following code in a file and I want to change the numeric value (`1000`) to whatever other value.

file:

```
//...
if (counter==(1000)) {
// ...
```

I have tried to use this command:

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]+/9999/g' file.cpp
```

but nothing changes.

Moreover, I want the change to be permanent. How do I do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as "permanent" :-) You mean "persistent". Do you know that the number you want to change is exactly `1000`, or that it's in parentheses, or that it occurs after `count==(`?  I'm asking because you probably don't want to change _every_ number in the code, right?

Comment: The number is not always 1000. And yes. It will occur in the `count==(`.
Yes the idea is to eventually make a bash script where I will substitute the number with a variable "grep"ed from a another file.

Comment: A little lateral thinking. "Magic" numbers in code are not helpful. Whatever language that code is, it will have variables. It would be much easier if that value was declared somewhere like `MaxCount=1000;`, because that would be much easier to identify with an edit, as relating to that specific instance of a number. Later, you might also consider making the value an external argument to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `+` quantifier from the [Extended Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) Syntax set, but `sed` by default uses Basic Regular Expressions. So, you need to turn on ERE by adding the `-E` flag:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9][0-9]+/9999/' file.cpp
```

or use the corresponding BRE construct

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{2,\}/9999/' file.cpp
```

which is more portable (as noted by @Stéphane Chazelas).

---

Note that this will modify *any line that contains two or more consecutive digits* by replacing that group with `9999`. If you want to ensure that only lines that conform to your example

```
if (counter==(1000)) {
```

are affected, I would recommend adding a suitable [address specifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) to make the matching more specific:

```
sed '/if (counter==([0-9]\{2,\}))/s/[0-9]\{2,\}/9999/' file.cpp
```

That way, the substitution would only be performed on lines that match `if (counter==(two-or-more-digit-number))`.

The `g` option doesn't seem necessary because in your input example, there is only one such digit group on the line.

---

In order to modify the file directly, most `sed` implementations now understand the `-i` flag for "in-place" modifications. Again, as correctly noted by @Stéphane Chazelas, if you use it in combination with other flags, be sure to make the ordering right, as `-i` expects a suffix for creating a backup file (which may be left empty on GNU `sed`, but is required in FreeBSD/MacOS implementations):

- `sed -i '' -E 's/.../.../'` will work on FreeBSD `sed`
- `sed -i -E 's/.../.../'` or `sed -Ei 's/.../.../'` will work on GNU `sed`
- `sed -iE 's/.../.../'` will not work as the `E` would be considered the backup suffix.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Btw, do we have a "canonical" answer dealing with the "locale-dependend collation order" problem of regular expressions that we can link to in cases like these?

Comment: There's [Difference between \[0-9\], \[\[:digit:\]\] and \d](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/414226) but one could write a book about that issue as the behaviour varies greatly between tool, OS, libc, other lib and version of all the above. [`bash` globs](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-02/msg00054.html) alone could have a whole chapter in that book. In practice `[0123456789]` is the only thing that is guaranteed to match only on those 10 digits characters (though in some locales could also match on parts of characters that include bytes 0x30..0x39 in their encoding).

Comment: Note that while GNU and FreeBSD added their `-i` independently around the same time, other BSDs added `-i` much later and went for the GNU approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your answer is much appreciated.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever You're welcome :)