# Prepend string to all lines shorter than a threshold

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a huge file where I want to prepend a `@` character to every line that is shorter than a certain threshold.

For example, let's say we have the following file

```
dddd
weowfpdvkdfpomcwdf[wedifkw[efkwcwfpmcsdlvcdvdvdfvbdffvd
13148-089-42094vj2-393-8-08923r234234r232
ssss
wvmigmfogvjjtgoprgfbkpgofkbgpfbokdfvdd
13012323432432-123421343-343432323-2322
```

and I want to modify all lines that are, say, 10 characters or less in length. Then the output should be:

```
@dddd
weowfpdvkdfpomcwdf[wedifkw[efkwcwfpmcsdlvcdvdvdfvbdffvd
13148-089-42094vj2-393-8-08923r234234r232
@ssss
wvmigmfogvjjtgoprgfbkpgofkbgpfbokdfvdd
13012323432432-123421343-343432323-2322
```

Comment: Do you know the specific length, or only that it is _smaller_ than a threshold?

Comment: @AdminBee there is a threshold

Comment: Then please share the threshold so we know how to help you. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. Should a `@` be added to any lines that consists of _exactly_ 4 characters and a newline? Should it be added to any line with a length <=4? Should it be added to the first line and then every third line after that? Are these fastq files by any chance?

Comment: @terdon I don't feel the necessity to specify a threshold. I specifically delineated that there is a threshold and that's enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your threshold is "10 or less characters", you can use

```
sed '/^.\{1,10\}$/s/^/@/' input.txt
```

This will use the address specifier `/^.\{1,10\}$/` to only process lines containing 1 to 10 characters, and then "replaces" the "beginning-of-line" by `@`.

Alternatively, as noted by @terdon:

```
sed 's/^\{1,10\}$/@&/' input.txt
```

This will replace any line containing 1 to 10 characters with `@`, followed by ["itself" (`&`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html). This approach might be (marginally) faster as it involves only one RegEx to process.

You can also use `awk`:

```
awk 'length($0)<=10 {printf "@"}1' input.txt
```

this will print most lines as they are, but on those lines smaller or equal to 10 characters, print a `@` first.

Comment: I was inevitable to write the [same answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639370/338177) :p (at least with `sed`).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity :):)

Comment: Is there any benefit in using `sed '/^.\{1,10\}$/s/^/@/'` instead of `sed 's/^.\{1,10\}$/@&/'` or `sed 's/^\(.\{1,10\}\)$/@\1/'`?

Comment: @terdon I don't think so. I think αғsнιη could well have left her answer undeleted, if you are referring to that. You could add your own answer with the `@&`-approach for completeness ...

Comment: Meh, it's the same basic idea. I was just wondering if there were some edge cases where having a separate test and substitution step would be helpful. I figured either this was the first approach that occurred to you, or you had thought of a complication I hadn't considered and both seemed equally likely :). I hadn't seen αғsнιη's.

Comment: @terdon It was indeed the first approach that came to my mind, probably because I recently modified [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638899/377345) in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```bsh
# the threshold is the '5'
$ sed '/^.\{1,5\}$/s/^/@/' file
@dddd
weowfpdvkdfpomcwdf[wedifkw[efkwcwfpmcsdlvcdvdvdfvbdffvd
13148-089-42094vj2-393-8-08923r234234r232
@ssss
wvmigmfogvjjtgoprgfbkpgofkbgpfbokdfvdd
13012323432432-123421343-343432323-2322
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **awk** utility we can do as shown:

```
awk '/.{10}./||($0="@"$0)' file
```

---

The stream editor **sed** can do likewise:

```
sed -e '
  s/./&/11;t
  s/^/@/
' file
```

- The threshold is 10 characters or less to trigger the prefixing.